# Why is tinyxml's FirstAttribute() return null in simple function?

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

Running on: Linux Mint 16, QtCreator 3.0.0 with Qt 5.2.0. tinyXML last version.

XML working with:

```
<users>
<user>
    <username>testadmin</username>
    <password>testpwd</password>
    <privileges>2</privileges>
</user>
<user>
    <username>testuser</username>
    <password>testpwd</password>
    <privileges>1</privileges>
</user>
```

Code that's not working:

```
void Server::loadUsersFile()
{
TiXmlDocument usersDoc("users.xml");
    bool loadOk = usersDoc.LoadFile();

    if(!loadOk) {
        cout << "Error opening users file" << endl;
        return;
    }

    TiXmlElement* rootChild = usersDoc.FirstChildElement("users");
    TiXmlElement* userChild = rootChild->FirstChildElement("user");
    TiXmlAttribute* pAttrib=userChild->FirstAttribute();
    cout << pAttrib->Name();
}
```

pAttrib is NULL and I can't understand why. Maybe I didn't get the Child/Attribute relationship. Help appreciated.

Comment: How is it relevant to Qt? What Qt code are you referring to? I do not seem Qt xml classes, etc in your code, fwiw. I would suggest to update the question if it is lacking, or just remove the qt tag to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @LaszloPapp You're right, this has nothing to do with the question. I've just put it there for info. Changed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `user` element doesn't have any attributes. Attributes are data defined in the start tag of an element, so for the `user` element to have an attribute it would have to look something like

```
<user type="posix">
...
</user>
```

where `type="posix"` is an attribute of the `user` element.

To get the `username` element in an element, perhaps you want

```
TiXmlElement* username = userChild->FirstChildElement();
```

or more safely

```
TiXmlElement* username = userChild->FirstChildElement("username");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XML doesn't *have* any attributes. It has text within elements, but no *attributes*.

If your XML had something like:

```
<user name="foo" />
```

then it would give you an attribute. And you could have multiple attributes of course:

```
<user username="testadmin" password="testpassword" privileges="2" />
```

You could either change your code, or change your XML to *use* attributes. If you do, I'd recommend that you ask for *specific* attributes rather than requiring that the username is the *first* attribute, for example.

If you're going to work with XML, it's important to know the terminology, otherwise you'll get very confused. It might be worth looking through an XML tutorial before going much further.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to stick to the "text inside elments" version because it seems easier to read. Thanks for the help! So, the code is:

```
void Server::loadUsersFile()
{
    cout << "Loading users list..."<<endl;

    TiXmlDocument usersDoc(this->fileUsersStr);
    bool loadOk = usersDoc.LoadFile();

    if(!loadOk) {
        cout << "Error opening users file" << endl;
        return;
    }
    TiXmlElement* rootChild = usersDoc.FirstChildElement("users");
    TiXmlElement* userChild = rootChild->FirstChildElement("user");

    TiXmlElement *usernameElem;
    TiXmlElement *passwordElem;
    TiXmlElement *privilegesElem;

    while(userChild)
    {
        usernameElem = userChild->FirstChildElement("username");
        passwordElem = userChild->FirstChildElement("password");
        privilegesElem = userChild->FirstChildElement("privileges");

        cout << "username: " << usernameElem->GetText() << endl;
        cout << "password: " << passwordElem->GetText() << endl;
        cout << "privilege:" << atoi(privilegesElem->GetText()) << endl;

        userChild = userChild->NextSiblingElement();
    }

    cout << "Finished loading."<<endl;
}
```